# Ubuntu Server only using 200/500GB on SSD

Tags: server, storage

I just installed Ubuntu Server on a 500GB SSD, and it seems like the mount for / is only using 200GB. Here's the output from df -h:

```
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                               7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                              1.6G  1.5M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  196G  7.4G  179G   4% /
tmpfs                              7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                              7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                          976M  104M  805M  12% /boot
/dev/sda1                          511M  7.8M  504M   2% /boot/efi
/dev/loop0                          28M   28M     0 100% /snap/snapd/7264
/dev/loop1                          55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1705
/dev/loop2                          69M   69M     0 100% /snap/lxd/14804
/dev/loop3                          97M   97M     0 100% /snap/core/9436
/dev/loop4                         126M  126M     0 100% /snap/docker/471
/dev/loop5                         258M  258M     0 100% /snap/nextcloud/21796
/dev/loop6                         260M  260M     0 100% /snap/rocketchat-server/1433
/dev/loop7                          16M   16M     0 100% /snap/wormhole/112
tmpfs                              1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/1000
```

Does anyone know why this happened, or how I can resize it? Thanks!

```
sudo parted -l

Model: ATA WDC WDBNCE5000P (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB   537MB   fat32              boot, esp
 2      538MB   1612MB  1074MB  ext4
 3      1612MB  500GB   498GB


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv: 215GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End    Size   File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  215GB  215GB  ext4
```

Comment: Probably something you selected during installation.  Olease update the question with the output of `sudo parted -l`

Comment: It looks like you have a LogicalVolumeManager (LVM) setup and the space is inside the LV ... anyone that "speaks" LVM fluently, that can help here ?

Comment: I haven’t really done anything with the server yet, I might just reinstall and be more careful

Answer (score 2):

I re-installed the server. If anyone else has this problem, re-install the server and un-check the LVM option. Select the storage device as a boot device and then select the same device with format ext64 (depending) and that’s what worked for me.